# How to use css class from global css file declared inside _app.js (Next.js)

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Pretty much as title..

I declared my global *styles.css* inside _app.js as follow:

```
import '../public/styles.css'
```

then inside a page **header.js** (/components/header.js) i'm using a class `.buttonPrimary` present inside above mentioned global css file, as follow:

```
          <a
            href={`/api/auth/signin`}
            className={buttonPrimary}    // THIS
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault()
              signIn()
            }}
          >
            Sign in
          </a>
```

but it throws error that the class doesn't exists.. I know I could do an import at the top of the page of the same global css file, but what would be the point of loading it globally inside _app.js then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to just use the class as a string

```
 <a
  href={`/api/auth/signin`}
  className="buttonPrimary"
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    signIn()
  }}
>
  Sign in
</a>
```

Your bundler will connect the css file to the final bundle, and react will render. As a result we get html:

```html
<a href="/api/auth/signin" class="buttonPrimary">Sign in</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the className as a string

```
<a
 href={`/api/auth/signin`}
 className="buttonPrimary"
 onClick={(e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  signIn()
 }}
 >
 Sign in
</a>
```